# Listado vacio de registros PDO + MVC + PHP

Tags: php, mvc, pdo

estoy trabajando en un Sistema de gestión de proyectos bajo el patrón MVC y el problema radica al momento de imprimir los registros de mi base de datos en el CRUD, simplemente se aprecian todas las filas que corresponden a mi tabla "triunfadores" pero vacías. Gracias de antemano aquí adjunto porciones de codigo pertenecientes al modelo,vista,controlador.

Modelo:

```
public function query(){
    $query = Conexion::query('SELECT * FROM triunfadores');
    $query -> execute();
    return $resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Controlador:

```
$triunfador = new IncluirTriunfador();
$datosT = $triunfador->query();
require_once '../vista/gestionar-triunfador-vista.php';
```

Vista (CRUD 'gestionar-triunfadores-vista.php'):

```
<table class="zoomIn animated table table-bordered table-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;width:74%;background-color:white;">

        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">ID</th>
          <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
          <th class="text-center">Apellido</th>
          <th class="text-center">Cedula</th>
          <th class="text-center">Trayecto</th>
           <th class="text-center">Sección</th>
          <th class="text-center">Condición</th>
          <th class="text-center">Acciones</th>
        </tr> 

        <?php

          foreach($datosT as $persona){

        ?>

        <tr>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["id"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["nombre_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["apellido_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["cedula_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["trayecto_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["seccion_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["condicion_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td>
            <a href="../controlador/anadir-triunfador-controlador.php"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-success" value="Añadir"></a>
            <a href="../controlador/actualizar-triunfador-controlador.php"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-primary" value="Actualizar"></a>
            <a href="../controlador/buscar-triunfador-controlador.php"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-info" value="Buscar"></a>
            <a href="../controlador/eliminar-triunfador-controlador.php?<?php echo "id=1"; ?>"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-danger" value="Eliminar"></a>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <?php

         }

        ?>


  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### El error

La tabla aparece vacía porque en el `foreach` has puesto esto:

```
      foreach($datosT as $persona){
```

Pero luego, a la hora de buscar cada dato por sus columnas haces esto por ejemplo:

<s>`echo $datosT["id"]`</s>

---

### La solución

**Para buscar los datos por sus columnas debes usar `$persona`, no <s>`$datosT`</s>**.

---

### Propuesta de optimización y de claridad

Visto lo visto, el código se puede mejorar, si así lo quisieras.

- Dado que esto se repite una y otra vez `<td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;">`, puedes ponerlo en una variable, aquí la he llamado `$tdOn`.  Para mantener un estándar, también he creado una variable para cerrrar las celdas, a la que he llamado `$tdOff`. En esos casos repetitivos usaremos esa variable. Por cierto, **no es una buena práctica poner estilos en los elementos directamente**. Se recomienda usar CSS para los estilos. En este caso, tú puedes indicar `font-size:13px;` para los `td` de la clase `text-center` en el CSS. Esto permitirá, en caso de querer cambiar algún día ese dato, de hacerlo en un solo sitio (en el CSS), y no tener que ir a buscar todas las tablas y td donde quiera que estén para cambiarlos.
- También, a mi juicio, el código gana muchísimo en claridad cuando evitas mezclar trozos de PHP con HTML. Para hacer eso podemos concatenar todo en una sola variable, trabajar todo en PHP y hacer `echo` de esa variable al final del todo.

  ```
  <?php
  $tdOn='<td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;">';
  $tdOff='</td>'; 
  $tablaHTML='<table class="zoomIn animated table table-bordered table-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;width:74%;background-color:white;">';

  $tablaHTML.=
          '<tr>
            <th class="text-center">ID</th>
            <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
            <th class="text-center">Apellido</th>
            <th class="text-center">Cedula</th>
            <th class="text-center">Trayecto</th>
             <th class="text-center">Sección</th>
            <th class="text-center">Condición</th>
            <th class="text-center">Acciones</th>
          </tr>';         

            foreach($datosT as $persona){
              $tablaHTML.='<tr>';
                  $tablaHTML.=$tdOn.$persona["id"].$tdOff;
                  $tablaHTML.=$tdOn.$persona["nombre_triun"].$tdOff;
                  $tablaHTML.=$tdOn.$persona["apellido_triun"].$tdOff;
                  $tablaHTML.=$tdOn.$persona["cedula_triun"].$tdOff;
                  $tablaHTML.=$tdOn.$persona["trayecto_triun"].$tdOff;
                  $tablaHTML.=$tdOn.$persona["seccion_triun"].$tdOff;
                  $tablaHTML.=$tdOn.$persona["condicion_triun"].$tdOff;
                  $tablaHTML.='<td>
                  <a href="../controlador/anadir-triunfador-controlador.php"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-success" value="Añadir"></a>
                  <a href="../controlador/actualizar-triunfador-controlador.php"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-primary" value="Actualizar"></a>
                  <a href="../controlador/buscar-triunfador-controlador.php"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-info" value="Buscar"></a>
                  <a href="../controlador/eliminar-triunfador-controlador.php?<?php echo "id=1"; ?>"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-danger" value="Eliminar"></a>
                </td>';
              $tablaHTML.='</tr>';
           }
  $tablaHTML.='</table>';
  echo $tablaHTML;
  ?>
  ```

Comment: correcto, pero parecía tan obvio que pensé que no le llegaban los datos

Answer (score 0):

porque no haces un var_dump donde te digo para ver que datos traes a `$datosT` si es el caso.

```
<table class="zoomIn animated table table-bordered table-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;width:74%;background-color:white;">

        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">ID</th>
          <th class="text-center">Nombre</th>
          <th class="text-center">Apellido</th>
          <th class="text-center">Cedula</th>
          <th class="text-center">Trayecto</th>
           <th class="text-center">Sección</th>
          <th class="text-center">Condición</th>
          <th class="text-center">Acciones</th>
        </tr> 

        <?php
var_dump($datosT);
          foreach($datosT as $persona){

        ?>

        <tr>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["id"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["nombre_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["apellido_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["cedula_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["trayecto_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["seccion_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td class="text-center" style="font-size:13px;"><? echo $datosT["condicion_triun"]; ?></td>
          <td>
            <a href="../controlador/anadir-triunfador-controlador.php"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-success" value="Añadir"></a>
            <a href="../controlador/actualizar-triunfador-controlador.php"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-primary" value="Actualizar"></a>
            <a href="../controlador/buscar-triunfador-controlador.php"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-info" value="Buscar"></a>
            <a href="../controlador/eliminar-triunfador-controlador.php?<?php echo "id=1"; ?>"><input style="width:88px;" type="text" class="btn btn-danger" value="Eliminar"></a>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <?php

         }

        ?>


  </table>
```

así puedes centrar más o menos donde está el error y nosotros ayudarte mejor.